# Disable Menu Item

Tags: android, android-menu

In my application of Android I have an activity "A" with a menu. I want to disable a menu item when you return from another activity "B". I am using the methods OnPrepareOptionsMenu and onActivityResult but I can not do it. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it. I got it. By onActivityResult I returned a string flag "dev"

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
     MenuItem m=menu.getItem(0);
     if (dev.contentEquals("1")){
            m.setEnabled(false);
            }
     return true;
    }

Thank you very much Agarwal and Shishir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as below but you must override onDestroy method of second activity and make isEnabled variable to true.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();

    if (isEnabled) {
        menu.add("item").setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        menu.add("item");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I got it. I got it. By onActivityResult I returned a string flag "dev"

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
     MenuItem m=menu.getItem(0);
     if (dev.contentEquals("1")){
            m.setEnabled(false);
            }
     return true;
    }

Thank you very much Agarwal and Shishir.

Answer (score 1):

Write an "if" logic where you add the menu items:

something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    if (isFinalized)
        menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
    return true;
}
```

Let me know if this is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I got it. By onActivityResult I returned a string flag "dev"

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    MenuItem m=menu.getItem(0);
    if (dev.contentEquals("1")){
           m.setEnabled(false);
        }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you very much Agarwal and Shishir